# iPhone 5C Messages crashing after showing no messages

Tags: iphone, ios, messages

When I open my iPhone 5C Messages, all that appears is a white screen that is frozen. It will close on it's own in a minute or so and it still appears as being open when you check to see what applications are open.

I have received two messages that I can not read or get to. How to fix the Messages?

Answer (score 1):

Start off by looking [here](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/apple/3470778/how-close-apps-in-ios-7/) for how to close open apps in iOS7. Close Messages, then try opening it again. If that fails, close Messages again, turn the phone off completely (by holding the sleep/wake button down), wait a few minutes, turn the phone on again and try looking at your messages again.